# adding swipe inside webview fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, swipe

I am very new in android apps development. I want to add swipe code in different webview fragment (not in MainAcitivity). I've followed many idea from stack-overflow, but I can't get actual solution for my requirement. I have following structure.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tabbed.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

        }

        },3000);
    }
}
```

**tabyeb.java** I want to add swipe in this fragment only(tabyeb.xml)

```
public class tabyeb extends Fragment{

    public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(netInfos != null)
                if(netInfos.isConnected())
                    return true;
        }
        return false;

    }


    public WebView mWebView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabinfo, container, false);
        mWebView = ((WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview));
       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setSaveFormData(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        if (isNetworkStatusAvialable(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }

        return v;
    }


}
```

**tabyeb.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="office.com.np.Tabbed$PlaceholderFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

           <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What you want to acquire. Attach some diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only your fragment class swipe code you need to extend view pager class inside the fragment class.[you can refer the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

either you can also create custom swipe Listener for fragment..

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 1;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
            }
            result = true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashokkumar Adichill

Comment: Haapy to help..@AnandaLC